# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'router' in django

Tags: django

```
from django.urls import path,include
from myapi.views import NoName

from rest_framework import routers

router=routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('thes',NoName)


urlpatterns = [
    path('',include('router.urls')),

]
```

Comment: Please, provide us more details about this question. What have you done so far?, Do you have tried something to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

based on Django Rest Document, you must use router like this:

```
from rest_framework import routers

router = routers.SimpleRouter()
router.register(r'users', UserViewSet)
router.register(r'accounts', AccountViewSet)
urlpatterns = router.urls
```

or in the another way:

```
router = routers.SimpleRouter()
router.register(r'users', UserViewSet)
router.register(r'accounts', AccountViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('forgot-password/', ForgotPasswordFormView.as_view()),
]

urlpatterns += router.urls
```

so for your code you must change it like this:

```
from django.urls import path,include
from myapi.views import NoName

from rest_framework import routers

router=routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('thes',NoName)

urlpatterns = router.urls
```

!!!Important you must use Viewset with DRF Router.